# Managing Hibernate concurrency with remote web service

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, concurrency, jakarta-ee

In Spring/Hibernate application. user may send more than on request with the same data to banking account. here is the case:
1st request reaches first, bank serve it, return OK, set local account data status OK;
2nd request reaches second, bank serve it, return NOK, set local account data status NOK;

Now our local account data status is NOK, although its served well.
Any suggestions for this problem.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. What does "with the same data" mean? You mean the same transaction might be transmitted more than once, but should only be processed once? Why do you think the account is "served well" if a request to it has been rejected?

Comment: Its just an example. Both could be accepted. If remote webservice returns say current balance after buy operation, when I update record this will make a big difference. Just last one will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

A. Make sure the recieving web service queues the requests.

B. Perform not more than a maximum of two threads executions at a time at the web service side. This will provide you clues on why the status is set to NOK.

Comment: I do not control webservice side

Comment: Is so break down the thread. Looks like the all invocations should be FIFO base.

Comment: Capture all requests into a Queue block and then control the number of requests sent to the web service.

Comment: But, this will prevent parallel requests

Comment: But you don't know how the recieving service handles request do you? a good way of understanding the way the remote service works is - if you start passing requests in incrementing order. For example one request at a time, followed by two requests ... and finally implement your full blown parallel routine.

Comment: There is another problem now:
controller requests can I edit account, remote webservice returns requested data object with confirm, controller validate object then requests edit account, remote webservice response with data object.

Comment: I think I need to lock controller job if I got another invocation for this particular object ... right?

Comment: Each *request* to your controller, with its cascade of activities before you get the data object from the web service will have different execution path. Therefore if each request edits the returned object, then yes it is advisable to lock objects under edit to a request to avoid race control issues.